# Microsoft Speech API speech segmentation and audio

Tags: speech-recognition, speech

I'm using Microsoft Speech API to do some speech recognition, and have found it fairly straightforward.  In addition the the transcribed/recognized text, I need to capture the audio segment that correspond to the text, e.g. if user say "I do", I need to keep the audio record of it - is there a standard way of doing it?

Answer (score -1):

Found something in their API example - will verify..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognitionresult.getaudioforwordrange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx